# Selecting latest item over a SQL PARTITION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

Note: I'm trying to learn window functions so while I could do this using GROUP BY - I'm explicitly setting out to use window functions

I have the following table of test results

```
| Id | TargetId | TestId | ResultId | TestedOn                 |
+----+----------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| 1  | 1        | 1      | 5        | 9/1/2017 6:28:32.220 PM  |
| 2  | 1        | 2      | 5        | 9/1/2017 6:28:32.220 PM  |
| 3  | 1        | 3      | 5        | 9/1/2017 6:28:32.220 PM  |
| 4  | 1        | 1      | 4        | 9/10/2017 6:28:32.220 PM |
| 5  | 1        | 2      | 4        | 9/10/2017 6:28:32.220 PM |
| 6  | 1        | 3      | 5        | 9/10/2017 6:28:32.220 PM |
```

I want to select the latest result for each test id - so I have the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TargetId,
    TestId,
    FIRST_VALUE(tr.ResultId) OVER (PARTITION BY TestId ORDER BY TestedOn DESC) LatestResultId
FROM 
    TestResult tr
```

I get the expected result

```
| TargetId | TestId | LatestResultId |
+----------+--------+----------------+
| 1        | 1      | 4              |
| 1        | 2      | 4              |
| 1        | 3      | 5              |
```

What I don't understand is why this query, where instead of using FIRST_VALUE, I use LAST_VALUE and sort accordingly, yet this yields a different result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TargetId, 
    TestId,
    LAST_VALUE(tr.ResultId) OVER (PARTITION BY TestId ORDER BY TestedOn) LatestResultId
FROM  
    TestResult tr


| TargetId | TestId | LatestResultId |
+----------+--------+----------------+
| 1        | 1      | 4              |
| 1        | 1      | 5              |
| 1        | 2      | 4              |
| 1        | 2      | 5              |
| 1        | 3      | 5              |
| 1        | 3      | 5              |
```

To me, these queries should yield the same result set.

Comment: What is TargetId? I don't see it in your table of test results?

Comment: Woops, it's missing from the result table - it's all 1, in every row. Will fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY TestId ORDER BY TestedOn
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

I believe the default for an ascending window functions is:

```
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql

Comment: My version of SQL doesn't seem to like the AND - will look over the docs

Comment: it should be `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`

Comment: So I take it, by default the window function only considers the preceding rows unless otherwise specified. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using with clause , something on the lines of

```
WITH N(TESTID,LATEST_DATE) AS

(SELECT DISTINCT TestId, Max(TestedOn ) OVER(PARTITION BY TestId) FROM TestResult)

Select TestId, ResultId from FROM TestResult TR join N ON TR.TestId = N.TESTID AND TR.TestedOn =N.LATEST_DATE
```

Table 'N' is just a temp table that has a list of TestID and LATEST_DATE